# C++ .lib when developing, .dll when running application

Tags: c++, dll, linker, .lib

I am using a company internal SDK. When installed, it provides a .lib file (xyz.lib for example) in both 32b/64b as well as two header files. When I create an application that utilizes the SDK I can build it, but when I try to run it, the application errors out saying it is looking for xyz.dll. Is the SDK supposed to include this DLL? Can I generate a .dll from the .lib file? From my research, it seems to be the other way around. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't have anyone in your company that you can ask for help using your *company internal SDK*?

Comment: A DLL based library will often come with two files, the .dll for running and a .lib for linking. The .lib is merely a stub, it doesn't contain any of the actual code.

Comment: Ken White, unfortunately no.

Comment: If you don't have the dll and cannot compile the SDK yourself, you may be out of luck. Time to start asking around the place, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

A DLL can be loaded in two ways, explicitly or implicitly.

Explicit DLL loading involves calling [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and then calling [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the address of an exported function you want to call.

[Implicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx) DLL loading is done at compile time by linking in a `lib` file that contains the definition of the exported functions. This adds a dependency to your DLL that will load the correct DLL at runtime.

Implicitly linked DLLs use the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine where to load the DLL from. It will load the first instance of the DLL it finds searching the locations noted in the order.

If you're linking against the `lib` file but the DLL can't be found, that means it isn't present anywhere in the search path.

Take the compiled DLL and stick it somewhere in that path. Usually the working directory of the application is fine.

Comment: But OP says they don't even have a dll, only a lib

Comment: Based on the phrase "when installed" I had assumed the DLL was installed but not to a location within the search order for DLLs, my mistake. If they don't have the DLL they can't do much except go and find it somewhere.